# Importing/Exporting, but not everything

Tags: import, export

I have a dev server and a production server, they are on two different databases. The editors will only be logging into the production space to add content. I'm looking for an easy (but still manual) way to export content. I rather not do an entire database dump every time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wish to just pull down the production environment to your development server? This is how we solve this problem at work, by only editing the production server's database and then pulling it when it is updated.

There are quality scripts for syncing environments from the command line. You can simply run `./pull_db.sh` and it will do everything for you.
https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts

There are also new craft 3 plugins for export/import but I have not had much success so far.

Comment: I thought about it more and I guess it does make the most sense to pull down everything.

Comment: I'm glad you agree, it can be one of the most dangerous parts of working with craft. It is easy to overwrite data, especially if you add a third 'staging' environment. I think a better solution is coming soon with the newer craft 3 plugins.